# What could the author mean?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

Currently going over Courant’s “Course in Differential and Integral Calculus” and in the problem section of the 1st chapter, subchapter 7 (“The limits of functions of a continuous variable”, or just the limits of functions) the author asks to “find the limits providing at each step the theorem on limits which justifies it”. By the latter, I am confused; for in the subchapter itself the author only states the formal definitions of limits of sequences/functions and the arithmetic operations which can be exercised upon limits. What should I understand by the “theorems on limits”? The arithmetic operations? Some other kind of fact? Take notice that there have been no explicitly stated *theorems* in the book so far, only some implicit results.

Comment: The theorems are the arithmetic rules. For example if you want to show that the limit as $x$ goes to $1$ of $x^2+x$ is $2$ you might show that each of the summands has limit equal to $1$ and then invoke the rule that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits.

Comment: Nicely detailed question , very few people are this precise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"the arithmetic operations which can be exercised upon limits". **Those** are theorems. The fact, for example, that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits (as long as those limits exists) **is a theorem**.

A theorem is any statement that is proved from the axioms or from previous theorems. It doesn't have to be labeled "Theorem" in a book to be a theorem.

Some times the books state the theorems calling them "Propositions", "Lemmas", "Corollaries", or even without any name, just proving some properties about the Mathematical objects been studied. **All** of those are theorems.